# Issues when upgrading from Excel 2010 to 2013

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, excel-2013

I've been working on a dashboard for the past several months in Excel 2010 and was nearing completion when we were upgraded to Excel 2013. I have experienced one issue that I'm completely stumped on...

I built a simple UI for the dashboard utilizing the first several rows of each sheet. Essentially, each sub-menu is hidden in a different row and only the appropriate rows are visible at any time. Is also allows the user to toggle on/off the various menus in/out of view without using a userform.

Prior to upgrading to 2013, it was very snappy and responsive, taking around 0.05 seconds each time a change was made in the UI. However, after migrating to Excel 2013 the UI is very sluggish. At first I thought it was a screenupdating issue because the screen was updating in bits and pieces - the labels, hidden rows, background color, etc would come in chunks, instead of all at once. I've ruled that out as a possibility.

I also tried disabling all of the annoying new animations that are baked into 2013. I tried all of the different methods I saw out there online - disabling the hardware graphics acceleration, turning off unnecessary animations in the ease of access center, etc. That too seems to have no effect.

After a full day of troubleshooting, I've noticed a sheet with just the UI and nothing else runs just as snappy as before. It's only when there are objects on the worksheet that things go wrong. From what I can tell, shapes and text boxes seem to have no effect on performance. Labels, both form control and Active X, seem to be the culprit.

I've noticed that the little bits of code I have for the UI continue to run at the same speed, but the screen will continue to change even after the procedure has run. This also totally perplexes me.  I have tried changing the property from Move and Size with Cell to Free Floating and neither seems to make any difference. I've also tried changing things like Print Object, Locked, etc.

I'm totally stumped as to how to resolve this issue. It's definitely something endemic to 2013 as the exact same file runs without issue on 2010. If anyone has any suggestions they would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: Here is a link to a sample file highlighting the issue. Both work fine when tested on 2010.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/r2ep5bgyn6ohjph/2013%20Issue.xlsm?dl=0

Comment: Can you include some actual code?  Always helps to have something specific to test.

Comment: Just added. I thought I could add an attachment but was wrong so went the dropbox route

Comment: Have a look here http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2015/04/07/excel-2013-vba-unreasonably-slow/ Some people have had luck with some suggestions in the comments, but I have had zero luck. You probably don't have a choice, but if you did I would stick with 2010 and see if they worked out the issues in 2016.

Comment: I was actually looking at that earlier Dick. That's what's bizarre is the code seems to run in roughly the same amount of time. It's the screen that seems to be lagging behind - still updating after the procedure has run.

Answer (score 0):

Granted this is a stretch, but a little bit of research tells me that Excel 2013 has suffered a number of problems with ActiveX controls. There were several patches Microsoft has released, so I recommend you install them first and make sure your copy of Excel 2013 is completely up to date.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3025036

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2956145

If this does not fix the problem, please let me know and I will remove this answer.

Comment: I'll have to check with IT. The issue appears to happen with form controls, though, and not just ActiveX

Comment: Have you had any luck?

Answer (score 0):

All, thanks for your help. I finally solved the issue I was having. I isolated the problem to Form Controls or ActiveX controls being visible at the time the code is run. I'm not sure why but the presence of either creates an issue. However, hiding all shapes prior to running the code and then unhiding them after resolves the issue. I did notice, however, this solution only works if the code does NOT turn screenupdating off prior to execution. I will post an updated file later when I have access to dropbox.